# Plot an Excel Chart where the date is on the x-axis and the different times as the Two Series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data like this in a table:

```
Date    Time        Min RTT
3/28/16 10:00 AM    42.91
3/28/16 10:00 PM    41.81
3/29/16 10:00 AM    70.61
3/29/16 10:00 PM    42.81
```

I would like to plot it where the dates are on the x-Axis and the two different series are the 10 am and the 10 pm values. The Y-Values are the Min-RTT.

I have been trying for hours and just can't get it to work the right way.

Could someone please point me in the right direction. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always time is 10 AM and 10 AM, You can write the Data as follow:

> Date          10:00 AM  10:00 PM
>   28-03-2016    42.91     41.81
>   29-03-2016    70.61     42.81
>   select all and Insert Chart choose column or line[image: you will get this chart]

You can switch Row/Column in Chart Tools, Design to have times as series

Comment: SuperSam Thank You! This is what I ended up doing.